# Set up a test development DB that's a separate mirror of production?

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to set up a development environment for our project that reflects the state of a production database, but any data modification on it would not be visible on the production. Does PostgreSQL provide features that would let me do that on the same database, for example making it feel as if the user had its own permamently uncommitted transaction?

Answer (score 0):

How would you want this to work?

Imagine you modified something in the development database, and then the production database gets modified in an incompatible way.
Should the change on the production system fail? Should replication error out?

You *could* probably accomplish such a setup with Slony, but that is complicated, puts extra load on your production system, makes schema changes complicated and won't make you happy for the reason mentioned above.

The idea to have modifications in the development database take place in an uncommitted transaction is interesting, but how could you develop in a reasonable way if you cannot test transaction handling and other transaction can never see the work of your own transaction?

I think the best solution is to have a test database that is regularly updated from the production system, ideally by automatically restoring your nightly production database backup (that would have the additional advantage of testing your backups).

Comment: Restoring the nightly backups sounds good, but sometimes I'd like to be able to copy production in the middle of the day - suppose a bug was found on production and we'd like to quickly test a solution.

Comment: In that case you can run `pg_dump`/`pg_restore` or - faster - `pg_basebackup`.